# Python list within list

Tags: python

I have two lists: `ra_list`, `e_list`.

`ra_list` is a list of random numbers, `e_list` is a list with tuples consisting on a number and a categorisation.

A number from ra_list is compared to the number in e_list, and its category is given, as follows:

```
ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]
e_list = [(7, A), (7, B), (6, C), (5,D)]

for x in ra_list:
     val = None
     for i in xrange(0,len(e_list)-1):


            if x[1] >= e_list[i][1] and x[1] < e_list[i+1][1]:
                 val = e_list[i][0]


            if val == None:
                 val = e_list[-1][0]


     print x, val
```

The current output looks like:   `5   D, 5   D, 6   C, 7   B, 7   B`

This runs partially fine, however when I have two numbers within two tuples with diferente categorisations only one is considered and selected as result (e.g. the program states that a 7 from ra_list is always B, but, as you can see, A is also 7)

Is it possible to implement a list within a list that will randomise between A and B?  Or if there was another categorisation with the same number, e.g. if A and B were 7 and C and D were 6, it'd randomly pick A or B and C or D.  I know that I can randomise through a list with:

```
    random.choice(list_of_duplicates)
```

But I'm struggling on how to create the list of duplicates and join it with the original list.

If anyone has a suggestion or can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.  Thank you!

EDIT

What it ra_list are floats, and thus in the range between element 1 and element 2? e.g.

```
    ra_list = [7.53, 3.42, 35.64]
    e_lst = [(a, 7), (b, 7), (c,8), (d,23)]
```

Output would be 7.53 a or b as its in the range between a,b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to randomly select , it would be easier to create a dictionary of the values:category , where category would be a list of categories , and then you can use `random.choice()` on that list.

For this you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) with the default value as an empty list `[]` , this function sets the default value to `key` if it does not exist, otherwise it returns the value for the key passed to it.

Example -

```
ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]

cate_dict = {}

#Creating dictionary of categories
for key,val in e_list:
    cate_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)

import random
for i in ra_list:
    cate = random.choice(cate_dict.get(i,[0])) #To handle cases where `i` does not have category, if this is not the case then you do not need the second argument to `.get`. Use something other than `0` if that is one of the categories.
    if cate != 0:  #To handle cases where `cate` is someother value that can be false in boolean context.
        print i,cate
```

Demo -

```
>>> ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]
>>> e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]
>>>
>>> cate_dict = {}
>>>
>>> #Creating dictionary of categories
... for key,val in e_list:
...     cate_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)
...
>>> import random
>>> for i in ra_list:
...     cate = random.choice(cate_dict.get(i,[0]))
...     if cate != 0:
...             print(i,cate)
...
5 D
5 D
6 C
7 B
7 A
```

Comment: I get a list index out of range error for your code

Comment: Exactly where do you get that?

Comment: cate = random.choice(cate_dict.get(i,[]))

Comment: Try the latest `0` version - `cate = random.choice(cate_dict.get(i,[0]))` . But still you should not get index out of range there. Hmm

Comment: runs but doesn't print

Comment: Are you sure you are using my exact code copy/paste?

Comment: can you show the `ra_list` and `e_list` you are using?

Comment: exactly the same lists as youre using

Comment: It worked for me in both python 3.4 as well as python 2.6 . try printing `cate` just before the `if` part and see what it prints.

Comment: everything is printed out as a 0

Comment: your ra_list is not same as the numbers in the `e_list` , for sure.

Comment: i've edited my question with a range question you might be able to help me with? if numbers in ra_list are floats, how will this change?  I'm not looking for string matching, but if it's between 7 and 8, its 7.

Comment: That is a different question , you should first accept one answer (any answer you feel like the best) for this question (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of that answer) . Then try that out yourself, and come back if you get stuck with exact code and where you got stuck, etc (as a different question) .

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension and random choice

**Code:**

```
ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]


import random

for element in ra_list:
    print random.choice([value for value in e_list if element == value[0]])

(5, 'D')
(5, 'D')
(6, 'C')
(7, 'B')
(7, 'A')
```

**Code1:**

```
import random

ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]

for element in ra_list:
    print element,random.choice([value[1] for value in e_list if element == value[0]])
```

**output:**

```
5 D
5 D
6 C
7 A
7 B
```

**Code2:**

```
ra_list = [7.84, 8.09, 7.40] 
e_list= [('a', 7.31), ('b', 7.31), ('c', 8.08),('d',7.84)]
import random

for element in ra_list:
    check_list=[value for value in e_list if element == value[1]]
    if len(check_list)>0:
        print random.choice(check_list)
    else:
        print element,"No-match"
```

**Output:**

```
('d', 7.84)
8.09 No-match
7.4 No-match
```

**Code3:**

```
ra_list = [7.53, 3.42, 35.64]
e_lst = [('a', 7), ('b', 7), ('c',8), ('d',23)]

import random
for element in ra_list:
    check_list=[value for value in e_lst if round(element) == value[1]]
    if len(check_list)>0:
        print random.choice(check_list)
    else:
        print element,"No-match"
```

**Output:**

```
('c', 8)
3.42 No-match
35.64 No-match
```

Comment: @user47467 can you show the full traceback I think there are some element in e_list with one value

Comment: @VigneshKalai Check my answer for finding the reason!

Comment: print element, random.choice([value[1] for value in e_list if element == value[0]])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @user47467 you have a value in ra_list which is not available in e_list

Comment: @user47467 could you provide values of both lists

Comment: I've tried a new list to my question, which has floats, ra_list = [7.84, 8.09, 7.40] and e_list [(a, 7.31), (b, 7.31), (c, 8.08)] can floats cause an issue?

Comment: @VigneshKalai now im getting no match for them all?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you asked earlier.  What it floats are in the range between element 1 and element 2? for example, 7.84 d, 8.09 c, 7.40, a or b

Comment: @user47467 could you give same input and output for this case

Comment: yes. for example, for code 2, 7.4 would be either a or b because its in the range between 7.31 and c 8.08

Comment: looking at ranges not exact matches

Answer (score 2):

First you can use a dictionary to preserve the numbers as a key and the corresponding characters in a list as values the use a function with `yield` to return a generator based on your condition :

```
>>> def printer(ra,e_list.d={}):
...     for i,j in e_list:
...       d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
...     for i in ra:
...         val=d.get(i)
...         if len(val)==1:
...              yield i,val[0]
...         else :
...              yield i,random.choice(val)
```

Demo :

```
>>> import random
>>> list(printer(ra_list,e_list))
[(5, 'D'), (5, 'D'), (6, 'C'), (7, 'B'), (7, 'B')]
>>> list(printer(ra_list,e_list))
[(5, 'D'), (5, 'D'), (6, 'C'), (7, 'B'), (7, 'A')]
>>>
```

Note that based on following benchmark this recipe would be pretty much faster on greater lists than @Vignesh Kalai's answer that called the `random` function on each list and used a nested for loop :

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""
ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]*100
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]


for element in ra_list:
    random.choice([value for value in e_list if element == value[0]])


"""

s2="""
ra_list = [5,5,6,7,7]*100
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]

def printer(ra,e_list,d={}):
     for i,j in e_list:
       d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
     for i in ra:
         val=d.get(i)
         if len(val)==1:
              yield i,val[0]
         else :
              yield i,random.choice(val)

list(printer(ra_list,e_list))

   """


print '1st: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000,setup='import random')
print '2nd : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000,setup="import random")
```

result :

```
1st:  3.390841960907
2nd :  1.092016124725
```

Comment: too much mate :p and by the way are you the downvoter

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes I was. :-)

Comment: downvoting just because the run time of answer was slow I think it is too harsh :P. Then you have to go on downvote many answer in SO:p

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of duplicates rater then creating a list of lists. Dict will be cleaner.

```
e_list = [(7, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (6, 'C'), (5,'D')]

from collections import defaultdict

res_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in e_list:
    res_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print res_dict #defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {5: ['D'], 6: ['C'], 7: ['A', 'B']})
```

Now you can go ahead and add your logic to get the desired output.